# How to drive a clock to a single clock domain?

Tags: delay, vhdl, clock, fpga

I have a project to do in VHDL on a FPGA (cyclone IV). The majority of my entities works with a single clock. I know that clock gating is not a good solution (see image) because it causes timing violations. Can someone tell me what are the good practice rules to do this kind of things? (I obviously did some researches on Internet but every link I found talks about clock domain crossing)
Thank you

[image]

Comment: The 'Hello' line is not taken in account...

Comment: What is your concern here?  Having a single clock domain is usually straight forward, and supported immediately by the synthesis and timing tools.  Do you see any problems or errors?

Comment: My concern is that (on the image) the output of 2nd flipflop does not change at the same time than the clock of the 3rd one because the delays are different and then the input of the 3rd flipflop can be incorrect. My errors are that the timing requirements are not met.

Comment: And what are your timing requirements and which ones are not met? Also, do you have anything special on the clock path (where `Delay=dC`) is located in your image?

Comment: If you are having trouble meeting timing on your design, it usually indicates that you have written your code poorly and you have too much combinational logic between your Flip-Flops.  Do not try to solve this problem by dividing your main clock domain to something smaller.  Solve this problem by optimizing your code and adding pipeline stages to break up the processing and have it take more clocks.  This will allow the tools more time to meet your timing requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram isn't a demonstration of clock gating. It is showing the impact of skew between different portions of a clock distribution tree. This is a reality of synthesizing any practical design even if you aren't gating the clock. A gated clock introduces additional skew on nodes within its fanout in addition to that which naturally occurs in clock distribution.

In non-trivial devices the clocks are passed through a tree of buffers to minimize capacitive load. In FPGAs the clocks are usually routed on carefully designed global clock nets that have been optimized to minimize skew. In ASICs balanced clock trees will be synthesized and physical timing constraints will guide placement of the buffers to minimize skew at the flip-flops. Unless you are doing something exotic, the backend tools will take care of getting you the best clock trees possible.

As a designer you primarily deal with the skew problem by setting up proper timing constraints and using static timing analysis to verify you meet setup and hold requirements under worst case (and best case) conditions. An FPGA has already had its delays characterized for use in static timing. With an ASIC, the delays in your design will be estimated before and after place-and-route and fed into the analyzer. A gated clock will introduce skew that reduces the available timing budget on the affected data paths. The timing analyzer will account for this if you have set up the constraints properly. Once you pass static timing on the final design, your job is done.

If you have timing failures due to combinational delays in your datapath You have to do one of the following:

- Reduce the failing combinational path by reorganizing the logic or inserting pipeline stages
- Use a slower clock
- Define a multi-cycle delay if you don't need valid results on every cycle

If a gated clock introduces too much skew you can think of it as creating a new clock domain altogether and using clock domain synchronization techniques to pass signals between the separate domains.